# Play a note of a certain frequency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

Is it possible to set a certain frequence in the audible range and have the iPhone play a note at that frequency?

I expect there might be a method like the following:

- (void)playNote(float frequency, float volume, float duration);

Comment: Attempt it yourself first, then ask for help.  Don't expect us to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Expect a function like `-(void) playNote(float frequence, float volume, float duration);`? That is a syntax error apart. And you probably meant **a method**, but even then it's still wrong. Also, what kind of waveform do you want? Sinus, square, triangle maybe?

Comment: I tried to clean up the question. Maybe it can be answered now.

Comment: Actually I would like to play single notes with their waveform emerging, so to say, as a result. As a matter of fact I would like to present a stream of virtually random digital information in audible form.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in or standard API for this.  But if you know how to draw your desired waveform, you can synthesize your sound waveform at your desired frequency and amplitude into a sequence of Audio Queue or Audio Unit RemoteIO buffers.

Comment: Yes, I may draw it: it is just a flat line: I just want to play a single note at various volumes. I will check those classes, thanks.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Core-Audio-Kevin-Avila/dp/0321636848/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1302255962&sr=8-1

Comment: Do you think it an appropriate introductions for my needs?